# "...many patients are seeking out transplants in other countries" -- what if "seek out" were used?

Tags: present-tense, present-continuous, present-simple

I was reading [an article on HowStuffWorks](http://health.howstuffworks.com/medicine/modern-treatments/organ-transplant2.htm) and came across this:

> The shortage of donated organs in the United States is so severe that many patients **are seeking out** transplants in other countries. In some countries, notably China, foreigners can buy the organs they need instead of waiting at home. These organs typically come from executed prisoners who have not volunteered to donate organs.
>
> This situation is extremely controversial in the organ transplant community. Paying for organs is considered unethical in most Western nations, as is the recovery of organs if the donor has not agreed to donate them. Furthermore, there is strong indication that execution schedules **are being modified** to meet patient demand.

I often see the progressive tense used in such a way on this site. What is the difference between *are seeking out* and *seek out*, and *are being modified* and *are modified*?

Comment: To me, **seeking out transplants** is an odd phrase.  We seek out *doctors* who do transplants when we are seeking a transplant.  But that is a separate question from the progressive.

Comment: It's just narrative voice.

Answer (score -1):

They essentially mean the same thing. The author probably didnt proof-read it to make sure it was perfectly efficient and compliant with english grammar. I think either way is acceptable but perhaps he used some unnecessary words, or even a colloquialism

Comment: We capitalize proper names in English. "Proofread" is not a hyphenated word. The question asks for the difference between the _present simple_ and _present progressive_ tenses, and there certainly is a difference—a Super Mega difference, in some cases.